# POWERSHELL: List all users/members in a specific AD OU Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to list the users/group members of a specific AD group in Powershell. I dont want to list everyone and everything, just the group members that I am interested in.

For example: I have a AD group called SqlAdmins. I just want to list the members/users in that group.

I tried this: " `Get-QADGroup -sizeLimit 0 | select @{name="GroupName";expression={$_.name}} -expand members | select GroupName,@{n='Member';e={ (Get-QADObject $_).name}}`" and it listed absolutely everything, but cannot work out how to list for only one group.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, it's a simple as:

```
get-qadgroup sqladmins | get-qadmemberof
```

i.e. get the AD group sqladmins, forward it to the next command which will enumerate all members.

As a general guideline for the Quest AD Cmdlets, if you end up writing something as complicated as you did just there for what must seem like a simple task, you're probably doing it wrong ;) Their AD cmdlets are truely excellent.

Comment: Thanks, but what I did before, was found on my old mate GOOGLE. I am brand new to using PS, so learning as I go, but this doing it all on one line is a bit confusing.

Comment: Try this great free ebook from Keith Hill: Effective PowerhShell - http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!6930.entry

Comment: @ryk do you get any output from "get-qadgroup sqladmins" ?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is some simple code that will help to query and export the list:**

```
Get-ADGroupMember "nameofthegroup" -recursive | Select-Object SamAccountName | export-csv c:/nameofthefile.csv
```

Now I need to know if is possible to exclude people based on another AD Security Group

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
get-qadgroupmember -identity "group name"
```

Comment: There seems to be already an accepted answer, may be if you can add some Context to your answer this might help others.